# Redirect wildcard subdomains to https

Tags: php, .htaccess, ssl, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect all wildcard subdomains to https and make a rewrite rule like this:

```
http://#.example.com => https://#.example.com => https://example.com/index.php?id=#
```

I have this code but it's not working and I'm not sure about the syntax.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.{2,})\.example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/index.php?id=%1 [P,L]
```

Comment: Page for user:
`http://#.example.com => https://#.example.com`

For server:
`https://#.example.com like https://example.com/index.php?id=#`

Answer (score 1):

Yo can do it with one `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$    https://www.example.com/index.php?id=%1 [L,R]
```